# Does Javascript remove event handlers of deleted DOM elements?

Tags: javascript, dom, memory-leaks

If I attached a bunch of events to some DOM elements - and then remove them - will the memory used for their event handlers or other attributes still be used?

I ask because I want to know if I will use a bunch of memory if I keep refilling an area of a page with new elements from AJAX requests and binding events to them - only to delete them and repeat the process when a new AJAX result comes in.

Comment: This isn't a direct answer, but if you're continuously adding new elements and removing old ones, I'd suggest using event delegation handle the events. It avoids this issue entirely.

Comment: ...that said, if possible I'd try to find a way to reuse the elements instead of destroying and recreating.

Comment: @RightSaidFred, yes - if the elements were related at all I could reuse most of the events using delegation. However, these are completely different pages loading for me.

Comment: I would think this would depend on the browser.  A removed dom element's event handlers should definitely be eligible for garbage collection, but it's entirely possible that older versions of IE may have had memory leaks.

Comment: Having said that, @RightSaidFred - is definitely right - using something like `$(document).on` is definitely preferable to attaching events directly to dom elements.

Comment: Just remove the event handler when removing the element, just to be sure. Also be careful about closures.

Comment: @Xeoncross: So you're saying even the behavior is completely different, not just the content?

Comment: @RightSaidFred, in my case yes, the behavior of the content that loads might be completely different from the content that previously occupied that area of the page. This is why I want to know if doing this is *memory safe* - or if I need to just refresh the page so the browser doesn't crash after doing this 20 or more times.

Comment: If the event handler was garbage collected then an attempt to rebind the code to another event would require a postback to the server to get the code.  So I believe event handler and other functions hang around in memory even if they are not attached to anything.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, modern browsers (eventually) release the memory used by event handlers in DOM nodes. However, old versions of Internet Explorer don't, so it's always good practice to remove event listeners before removing the nodes from the DOM.

This is a good article for understanding what's going on: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250448(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: A minor comment: IE's erroneous behavior was related to event handlers holding references to the elements they were attached to.

Comment: The publication date of that article is June 2005. This answer is from 2011.  "old versions of Internet Explorer" is a bit ambiguous but I presume would mean [IE 8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_8) or earlier given IE 9 was the latest stable in 2011. This is still a somewhat open question to me...