# Do I need to call removeEventListener before removing DOM elements?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Say, I have the following HTML:

```
<div id="myDiv">
</div>
```

where I dynamically added the *child* html with its own click event handler as such:

```
document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = 
      '<input type="button" id="idBtn" value="+">';
document.getElementById("idBtn").addEventListener("click", onClick);
```

and then upon a certain user action on the page I change it by removing elements within the `div` as such:

```
document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = "";
```

Do I need to call `removeEventListener()` on `idBtn` before I do that?

PS. This may be a recurring operation on the single page.

Comment: It was asked before, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8547363/does-javascript-remove-event-handlers-of-deleted-dom-elements.

Answer (score 0):

Insert

```
var Element = document.getElementById('idBtn');
Element.parentNode.removeChild(Element);
```

before

```
document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = "";
```

Listeners of element will be removed with element

Answer (score 0):

Yes Its a good practice to call removeEventListener() before removing DOM elements. Otherwise many problems can be arises to your webpage

Comment: OK. But what should one do if `addEventListener` was called implicitly by a library, such as jQuery? For instance, as such `$(".className").click(function(e){doStuff();});`?